# ASP.net Routing and Globalization

Tags: asp.net, routes, navigation, sitemap, globalization

The following files:

```
~/Admin/Dashboard.aspx
~/Admin/Welcome.aspx
```

are routed as

```
administrator/{culture}/dashboard/
administrator/{culture}/welcome/
administrator/dashboard/ (for invariant culture)
administrator/welcome/ (for invariant culture)
```

**SiteMap**

```
/administrator/dashboard/
/administrator/welcome/
```

The information from site map is loaded into a tree control.

**Scenario**

A user chooses French as desired language from a list control, which is saved in session.

**Problem**

How to reflect the change in the navigation (tree control)?

```
administrator/fr/dashboard/
administrator/fr/welcome/
```

I am in the middle of InitializeCulture() event in base page class. I could have used Response.Redirect and perform an ugly find and replace to tree's databind event, but that must not be a proper way to do so.

Comments are more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Sitemaps and url rewrite (routing) doesn't play well.

[1] implement a method which can take page path as argument and returns correct url rewritten path:

> GetUrl('/Admin/Dashboard.aspx') 
>   which will return you the string url, based on the url params and invariant culture etc.

[2] in sitemap use normal urls. /Admin/Dashboard.aspx

[3] when you bind tree, you need to use `GetUrl` method to update your urls.

Same way if you are using sitemappaths, that will also be handled in same way.

That's how I am doing in most of the projects I have.